# How to capture all keyboard events with another thread than the UI thread in WPF?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, user-interface, keyboard, capture

I want all keyboard events fired on a WPF window be handled by another thread than the UI thread. How can I separate UI rendering and keyboard capturing?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't.  Only the main thread can create UI objects or handle UI objects events.   What do you want and why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any super elegant way to do this, did you want something other than...

```
private void KeyPress(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bgWorkerKeyPress.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: Exactly, I don't want to create a new thread each time a key was pressed.